# Android app persists static data member of Activity class

Tags: java, android

I have declared a static member in my MainActivity class as below :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
    public static int logNum = 0;
    ...
}
```

I am incrementing this variable value in other methods.

The strange thing is that when I close this app & run again the value is not initialized to zero rather it takes the last incremented value onwards..

I am running this on Eclipse emulator. Is this emulator problem?

I don't want the solution. I can obviously initialize the variable to zero in `onCreate()` method. Just want to know WHY??

And I did not click on home button rather back button and also checked `onDestroy()` is being called.

Comment: it will persist until the app process is running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Static data persists until one of the following happens:

- The VM terminates.
- The process terminates.
- The class is unloaded.

Now, as far as I know, Dalvik doesn't unload classes so the lifetime of your statics is really bound to the lifetime of the process.

Even if `onDestroy()` is called on the activity, the process itself can be running indefinitely for caching purposes. When you relaunch the app, this cached copy is brought back.

Further reading: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Now, code that has a `public static` variable in an activity that is modified from all over does have certain bad smells in it...

Answer (score 3):

**static variable lifetime**

Static variables are associated with a class and they will live as long as the class is in the memory,and destroy when class gets unloaded (which very rarely happens).

In Android you have seen that when we close any application then it does not close completely, It remains in the recent application stack, That you can see by long press the home button(On Most Devices).

Android itself kicked out those recent app when the other app needs memory

In Android, static variable unload when-

- You force stop your app.
- Application crashes.
- You clear your app data.
- Switch off your Device.
- Android kicked out recent app

Thanks to Tarun Droid for the source.

Answer (score 2):

A static variable (doesn't matter where it is declared) will survive past the duration of the Activity's life cycle and will only be reset when the process' VM is closed and restarted by the system - this will happen sometime after there are no Activities in the started state / Services and other components associated with the process are active. There is no guarantee when it will occur.